# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis in Oracle. No error in pgAdmin sql editor

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm getting this error with a SQL statement in Java using the executeQuery method.
That's not strange despite having checked it many times; The fact is that I tried that statement in the pgAdmin SQL editor against a postgres database and it works properly.

Then, I tried it in Java, as I mentioned, against an Oracle database into a Virtual Machine. Others querys works properly.

This is the SQL statement:

```
SELECT pais_nombre, 
       golestotal 
FROM   (SELECT pais_nombre, 
               SUM(goleslocal) + SUM(golesvisita) AS golesTotal 
        FROM   ((SELECT seleccion.pais_nombre, 
                        goles_local AS golesLocal, 
                        0           AS golesVisita 
                 FROM   (encuentro 
                         join seleccion 
                           ON encuentro.seleccion_local_nombre = 
                              seleccion.pais_nombre) 
                ) 
                UNION ALL 
                (SELECT seleccion.pais_nombre, 
                        0            AS golesLocal, 
                        goles_visita AS golesVisita 
                 FROM   (encuentro 
                         join seleccion 
                           ON encuentro.seleccion_visitante_nombre = 
                              seleccion.pais_nombre)))AS 
               goles 
        GROUP  BY goles.pais_nombre) AS selecciones 
WHERE  golestotal = (SELECT DISTINCT Max (golestotal1) 
                     FROM  (SELECT pais_nombre, 
                                   SUM(goleslocal1) + SUM(golesvisita1) AS 
                                   golesTotal1 
                            FROM   ((SELECT seleccion.pais_nombre, 
                                            goles_local AS golesLocal1, 
                                            0           AS golesVisita1 
                                     FROM   (encuentro 
                                             join seleccion 
                                               ON 
                                    encuentro.seleccion_local_nombre = 
                                    seleccion.pais_nombre) 
                                    ) 
                                    UNION ALL 
                                    (SELECT seleccion.pais_nombre, 
                                            0            AS golesLocal1, 
                                            goles_visita AS golesVisita1 
                                     FROM   (encuentro 
                                             join seleccion 
                                               ON 
                                    encuentro.seleccion_visitante_nombre 
                                    = 
                                    seleccion.pais_nombre)))AS 
                                   goles1 
                            GROUP  BY goles1.pais_nombre) AS a);
```

Sorry for Spanish!

Comment: Which RDBMS against which you ran this query?

Comment: @Rahul ORA-00907 in the sense Oracle and also he mentioned in tag list

Comment: @VigneshKumar, have seen that already but have you also noticed he have mentioned postgres in question. So it's always better to confirm once.

Comment: Query you have posted have no missing `)`. Are this the entire code ...?

Comment: Try developing it with Oracle SQL Developer if you are going to use it for the oracle db.

Comment: I solved it using SQL Developer, I mistakenly assumed it was the same if I tried it with pgAdmin, it's not the same how it works with parenthesis. Tanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand this part since it is not a valid sql statement:

```
Select seleccion.pais_nombre, goles_local as golesLocal, 0 as golesVisita from 
(
   encuentro join seleccion on encuentro.seleccion_local_nombre = seleccion.pais_nombre
)
```

I think you actually mean

```
Select seleccion.pais_nombre, goles_local as golesLocal, 0 as golesVisita from encuentro
  (join seleccion on encuentro.seleccion_local_nombre = seleccion.pais_nombre)
```

In this case the parenthesis are not needed.

In any case, since you say your code works in other places, maybe if you got rid of some of the `(` `)` you don't need.

You can also refactor with CTEs:

```
WITH goles AS
(
    Select seleccion.pais_nombre as pais_nombre, goles_local as golesLocal, 0 as golesVisita 
    from encuentro 
    join seleccion on encuentro.seleccion_local_nombre = seleccion.pais_nombre
    UNION ALL
    Select seleccion.pais_nombre, 0 as golesLocal, goles_visita as golesVisita
    from encuentro 
    join seleccion on encuentro.seleccion_visitante_nombre = seleccion.pais_nombre
), selecciones as
(
  Select pais_nombre, sum(golesLocal) + sum(golesVisita) as golesTotal
  from goles 
  group by goles.pais_nombre
)
Select pais_nombre, golesTotal from selecciones
where golesTotal = 
(
  select distinct max (golesTotal) from selecciones
);
```

Comment: @Rahul - there aren't any.  But see my comment above about the funky join syntax.  That was probably what was messing up the parser.

Comment: I doubt so; BTW, don't mind I have posted the comment in your answer. I don't mean anything wrong in your answer. Just thought of putting it to see if you have found missing `)`

Comment: Yes, I don't need some parenthesis, I put them to make it clearer for me. Still it doesn't work, same error.

Comment: @Tony - try the refactored version above.

Comment: I tried it, changed the join syntax and still the same error. 

The CTE solution you suggested (I didn't realized to do it that way) gives me an "invalid character" error in Java against Oracle. However, it works correctly in pgAdmin sql editor against a postgres dbase.

Comment: Sounds like u have an issue using java+oracle